# Passing Guid to Command Line parser Library in C#

Tags: c#, command-line-arguments

I am using the nuget package [Command Line Parser](https://commandline.codeplex.com/) for parsing command line arguments in C#.

How do I pass a GUID from command line?

> ApplicationName.exe -g="3a0e5412-0971-4e0e-aebc-29dd09907b31"

does not work.

My CommandLineArgs class is

```
[Option('g', "sampleguid", Required = true, HelpText = "Enter a sample GUID")]
public Guid MyGuid { get; set; }
```

Comment: Can you describe "does not work"? What is the result? Is there an exception?

Comment: Parser.Default.ParseArguments(args, commandLineArgs) returns false

Comment: Check the documentation and see if there's a way to check the actual reason why it returned false. You might even be able to find it by rooting around in Intellisense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from [GUID is not working for input parameter](https://github.com/gsscoder/commandline/issues/241), the Guid parsing issue was already fixed. (However, if you use Guid?, it still does not work.)

Answer (score 2):

First, there is no built-in functionality for `Guid`. Second, make sure you're using the latest version `2.6.0.5`. You can install it through nuget -> search for "**CommandLineArgumentsParser**".

Once you've installed the latest version, you can interpret custom structures as such:

```
var parser = new CommandLineParser.CommandLineParser();

var guidArgument = new ValueArgument<Guid>('g', "guid", "Guid of something");
guidArgument.ConvertValueHandler = Guid.Parse;

parser.Arguments.Add(guidArgument);

parser.ParseCommandLine(args);

// the actual guid from command line.
var parsedGuid = guidArgument.Value;
```

If you want to keep your current version, you need to treat `Guid` as `string` when parsing, and later do `custom validation` by yourself.

http://commandlineparser.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=More%20thorough%20examples&referringTitle=Home

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried dropping the "=" and using a " " (space) instead?

Like: ApplicationName.exe -g "3a0e5412-0971-4e0e-aebc-29dd09907b31"

Comment: +1: In the land of Unix/Linux, arguments attached to "short options" must be specified as either `-x <some-argument-value>` or "-x<some-argument-value>". If the app supports *argument bundling*, where short options are concatenated together (e.g., `-a -b -c` can be specified as `-abc`, the option that takes the argument must be the last option in the bundle and the argument is either the remainder of the spec (`-abcx<some-argument-value>` or the next work on the command line (`-abcx <some-argument-value>`.